# Want to make my SELECT query simple when querying 2 or more tables with identical format

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 identical tables that have the same format but populated with different data.

I want to do a `SELECT` query with `group by` and `order by` but do not want to use a `UNION` since it makes my query very long.

Here is a sample that works:

```
(SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, MIN(h) as h, i 
 FROM `table1` 
 WHERE a LIKE '%this%' AND b LIKE '%that%' 
 GROUP BY b, a,c) 
UNION 
(SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, MIN(h) as h, i 
 FROM `table2` 
 WHERE a LIKE '%this%' AND b LIKE '%that%' 
 GROUP BY b, a,c) 
ORDER BY 
    b DESC, h ASC, c ASC
```

Is there a more elegant way to make the query work?

Something like

```
(SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, MIN(h) as h, i 
 FROM `table1`,`table2` 
 WHERE a LIKE '%this%' AND b LIKE '%that%' 
 GROUP BY b, a, c) 
ORDER BY 
    b DESC, h ASC, c ASC`
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `union all` in a subquery:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, MIN(h) as h, i
FROM ((select table1.*
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select table2.*
       from table2
      )
     ) t
WHERE a LIKE '%this%' AND b LIKE '%that%'
GROUP BY b, a,c
order by b DESC, h ASC, c ASC
```

I assume the query is just representative, since you have `e, f, g, i` in the `select` with no aggregation functions.

Comment: Also, if you are going to be querying across these tables often, consider a `view` instead of a subquery. +1 on this answer.